# Access Control Lists (ACLs) symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a website with Symfony2  in which each user can create their own blog and registration will be done with FOSuserBundle.
It will be also an entity named Blog related ManyToOne with entity User.
My question is, in this case shall I use **Access Control Lists (ACLs)** to define the authorization for each user to manage his own blog  ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember looking into ACL for a project some time back and on the face of it is seemed useful, if a little verbose - nothing wrong with that per sé. They seemed to perform quite well too.

However we decided against using it in the end because there were specific limitations that I cannot actually recall now. I know this is not very useful! It does sound pretty suited to your use case however, and if I recall correctly, it's pretty handy using [permission map](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html#pre-authorization-decisions) attributes with [`is_granted`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control-in-templates) in your templates (assuming you're using twig) something like:

```
{% if is_granted('EDIT', blog_post) %}
    <a href="{{ path('blog_edit', blog_post)">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

I'd suggest trying it out, although the documentation also suggests [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) as an alternative, but I've never used these so I cannot comment.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: but we should secure the methods in the controller also

Comment: Absolutely, that's always good practice. The above code snippet is useful say, in an example where you want to reuse a single template in a number of user contexts. I like using annotations in controllers so the `@Security` annotation  is useful in that case - you can define `has_role` and `is_granted` assertions for your controller's actions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html